# Split all hours froms now untill the end of the day

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So I wanted to split all the remaining hours of the day into an array, for example if the actual time was 3:00pm id like to have an array such as [4pm, 5pm, 6pm, 7pm, ... , 11pm]

I tried something like this using moment.js without luck

```
var now = moment().startOf('hour');
$('div').append(now + "<br>");
var count = 0;
while (now < moment().endOf('day')) {
  count += 30;
  now = now.add(count, 'minutes').format("hh:mm a");
  $('div').append(now + "<br>");
}
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Your question seems to imply that you want [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zcuqanf7/), but I'm unsure what you're doing, or why, with the additions of the 30 minutes?

Comment: Please consider upvoting helpful answers and/or accepting an answer if you deem it satisfactory!

Answer (score 0):

You *could* just make a list containing all the hours and remove the `n`th first entries, where `n` is the current 24 hour time, like this:

```
var now = moment().startOf('hour');
var all_hours=['12pm', '1am', '2am', '3am', '4am', '5am', '6am', '7am', '8am', '9am', '10am', '11am', '12am', '1pm', '2pm', '3pm', '4pm', '5pm', '6pm', '7pm', '8pm', '9pm', '10pm', '11pm'];
var remaining_hours=all_hours.slice(parseInt(now.format("H")), all_hours.length-1);
```

That being said, I assume the reason you're doing a loop is because this is an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and not really what you'd do in production. So basing it on your example, the following should work

```
// Get current hour
var now = moment().startOf('hour');
// Get the 24 hour time
var this_hr_int24=parseInt(now.format("H"));
// The list to contain the remaining hours
var remaining_hours=[];
// Initialize loop variables
next_hr_int24=this_hr_int24;
next_hr=now;
// While the number in next_hr_int24 is less then 24
while (next_hr_int24 < parseInt(moment().endOf('day').format("H"))) {
  // Increase by 60
    var count = 60;
  // Next hour of day
  next_hr = next_hr.add(count, 'minutes')
  // Get the 24 hr time for the next hour
  next_hr_int24 = next_hr.format("H")
  // Get the am/pm value for the list
  next_hr_apm = next_hr.format("h a")

  remaining_hours.push(next_hr_apm);
}
```

Comment: So the first examples would be a better practice for production? Would it work the same way if I each hour had its hour on the clock "2:00pm" and half hour more "2:30pm". Thanks for your help

Comment: @fmonper1 a rule of thumb is that you don't want to use `for` loops unless you have to.  Another thing here is that, in the first example, there are less function calls and more built-ins which (often) makes the code easier to read and faster to execute.